# Looping Conditional in play framework 1.2

Tags: loops, view, playframework, frameworks, conditional-statements

recently I wanna make view html that contains List Variable for instance "Y". so I decide to write

```
#{list items:Y, as:'x'}
${x.id}
#{/list}
```

but, I wanna make the condition inside the looping which will print, let's say "
" in every 3 times looping. so the result will be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and so on. anyone can help? I knew the logic, if in php just using `if ((somevar % 3) == 0){ echo "<br/>"; }`
but I just can't understand if implement it in groovy template. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already find the answer, using `%{ your logic code }%` i just read the documentation, add %{}% to begin the script excution :)

Answer (score 0):

You may check that question, that tells you how to get element index.

[How to get iterator's index in Play's template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923208/how-to-get-iterators-index-in-plays-template)

As you called it 'x', would look like

```
#{list items:Y, as:'x'}
  ${x.id}
  ${x_index % 3 ==0? '<br/>' : ''}
#{/list}
```

For more [information](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/tags#list)